# Linking records with record expansion in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, record-linkage

I have a large dataframe that looks something like that:

| id | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 125 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 4 | 200 |

```
tibble(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
       x = c(123, 123, 125, 125, 200))
```

I want to link my records and expand them. I.e. where they have the same `x`, they should have the same id. Note, record `id` 2 & 3 are considered same entity because of their shared link with 1. In other words, without record `id` 1, records 2 and 3 will not link. I'd also like to give it the smallest `id` value where the records link.

Results should look something like:

| id | x |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 125 |
| 1 | 125 |
| 4 | 200 |

Answer (score 4):

An equivalent way to restate this problem is "if the data frame represented the 'to' and 'from' nodes of a directed graph, what would be the first ID of each unique *component* of the graph?"

We can show this graphically:

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
             x = c(123, 123, 125, 125, 200))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
```

If we plot the graph, we will see that there are two unconnected clusters of nodes (called *components*); one for the grouped IDs 1:3, and one for ID 4:

```r
plot(g)
```

[image]

We can use the function `components` to work out which group each ID belongs to, and get the `first` ID in each group:

```r
comp <- components(g)$membership

df %>%
  mutate(group = comp[match(id, names(comp))]) %>%
  mutate(id = first(id), .by = 'group') %>%
  select(-group)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>      id     x
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   123
#> 2     1   123
#> 3     1   125
#> 4     1   125
#> 5     4   200
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>